# ETA for WorkGroup Manager 10.10

Tags: osx-server, user-account, macos, group

Anybody have any idea if / when Apple is planning on releasing WorkGroup Manager for 10.10? I dug around Google but couldn't find anything. Otherwise, I'm not upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but things do not look good for Workgroup Manager.

From http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1822:

> Note: Workgroup Manager and previous versions of Server app are not compatible with Yosemite.

Comment: I think Alistair has seen the same "writing on the wall" as many professional Mac admins. The old workgroup tools and MCX extensions are being shown the door and are unlikely to make a recovery.

Comment: That's just sad. I'm on hold with an Apple Care advisor right now to see what I can figure out, but no one seems to have any indication one way or the other (at least on behalf of apple support).

Answer (score 2):

I fired up WGM on my Lion Server and connected to the Local Directory of a freshly installed 10.10 server with no problem. That's a start but of course I have to try again once I have set up OD.

Comment: I suppose this is a very viable option for people that really need the functionality that Work Group Manager offered. LDAP is LDAP and you might very easily get it federated or managed by a "non-supported" product as long as that product works for you and you have hardware to keep on 10.7 so that the tool can run. A virtualized Lion might also be a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke to Apple Server support. After first informing them that Apple has 'announced' via the above post that Workgroup Manager is no longer being updated, he then checked something and advised me Workgroup Manager should still work in Yosemite (it doesn't, at least not according to my testing so far).
He also suggested fill in the relevant Apple Feedback form http://www.apple.com/feedback/server.html start a campaign, bring back Workgroup Manager!
Had I known in advance OSX Server 10.7 - 10.9 in general would be so flaky I would not have spent £££1,000s on a new Mac server. Now I can no longer risk an upgrade because of Workgroup Manager. Annoying, but you live and learn.

Comment: WGM and MCX have been deprecated in favor of the new version of Server and using configuration profiles.  I certainly agree that Server has not been anywhere near as stable as it was was in SL, but profiles can do quite a lot and in many cases much more easily than WGM/MCX could.

Comment: ok thanks I will try and have a look at configuration profiles, although we have deliberately tried to keep things simple as possible with our setup. It does all seem to point to a gradual phasing out of OSX Server going back to Lion, one things guaranteed after 10+ years on Macs, the next server we purchase will be Windows, and probably then gradually switch our 80 or so workstations from Mac to PC.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that sending feedback to http://www.apple.com/feedback/server.html is probably our best chance of getting Workgroup Manager (or an adequate replacement) made available. Many key/essential multi-user lab management tools are not possible with Profile Manager. We are still running 10.9 server with 10.10 clients (OK so far) for this year but I know that it is only a matter of time!!!!! I am hoping that Apple will not abandon multi-user lab situations/academic (K-12 and Higher Ed).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Your answer seems more of an opinion and does not provide an answer to the question. If you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you can leave a comment to the other answer. Please consider improving or deleting your answer.